# Is it possible to get the actual class type from within a base class?

Tags: c#

Revisiting some old C#8 code after working in Swift for the past few years and am hitting a wall.  Well, an annoying speed bump anyway.

Swift has a great language feature where the type `Self` always refers to the instantiated type, even if you are within a base class (although from within the base class, you still only have access to the base class members.) This means if you have a function or property of type `Self` it will always be of the instantiated type at the call site.

Here's an illustrative example. Not sure if this compiles as I'm typing off the top of my head, but you get the idea.

```
abstract class Foo {

    public Foo ReturnMe(){ // Note the return type 'Foo'
        return this;
    }
}

class Laa : Foo {}
var laa = new Laa();
var x = laa.ReturnMe(); // x is of type 'Foo', not of type 'Laa'
```

However, by changing the return type of `ReturnMe` to `Self`, something magical happens...
(Of course this won't compile. This is illustrative only.)

```
abstract class Foo {

    public Self ReturnMe(){ // Note the return type 'Self' here, not 'Foo' as before
        return this;
    }
}

class Laa : Foo {}
var laa = new Laa();
var y = laa.ReturnMe(); // 'y' here is type 'Laa' not 'Foo' thanks to 'Self'

class Hee : Foo {}
var hee = new Hee();
var z = hee.ReturnMe(); // Like above, 'z' here is type 'Hee'
```

It's such a helpful feature because it allows you to easily create chainable, fluent-style interfaces without losing type along the way. As an example, you could do this...

```
x.doSomething().thenSomethingMore().andEvenmore();
```

Even if those methods were all defined in base classes, whatever type `x` is is the type passed on down, meaning all base and subclass members would be available, not just those in the base class.

So, does C#8 have any such mechanisms?

Comment: you can use generics to help with that. c# 9 has covariant return types too.

Comment: That's what I was leaning to, but it's such a shame you have to bring along generics because it means you're basically doing `class Laa : Foo<Laa>` manually.  But it does work.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on (or link to) `Covariant` types and how they would apply here? I mean you can already 'sort of' do that with the `new` operator. I actually do that quite frequently (and yes I know the `new` operator doesn't solve the issue when accessing it via the base class type.)

Comment: its not GA but: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#covariant-returns

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I already do that by 'newing' over the base class type to essentially achieve the same thing.  Plus, it still requires the override.  I think the generic is how I have to go.  If you put that in an answer, after the couple of days it makes me wait, and provided there isn't something better fitting, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah you will always have to overload to update the signature when using the new C# 9 covariant return types, even if it's just `public override Laa ReturnMe() => this;` (although that's not really much to type)

Comment: It actually kind of is if you have a long hierarchy chain as you have to do that at each and every level, and you have to do that for each and every member/function where you need it.  Using `Self` in Swift, you just get all of that for free, implicitly. It's implicit covariance.  I wonder why they don't just try the same with `This` for the type of `this` the way they use `Self` as the type of `self`.

Comment: People are asking about that in [the github topic on covariant return types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49#issuecomment-663138852).